# Trying to make a timed text come out

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to use javascript to make a timed text appear.

The following code Im using is this

```
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    (function toggle_visibility(id) {
setTimeout (var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.display == 'none')
e.style.display = 'block';
else
e.style.display = 'none';
,1000);
</script>
<a onclick="test('foo');"><b><u>Click to view</b></u></a><div id="foo"      style=display:none;>TEXT</div>
```

This script is not working, but how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:

1. function name is `toggle_visibility` not `test`
2. There are syntax error in your function
3. Even HTML has problems

*JavaScript*

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element.style.display == 'none') {
            element.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            element.style.display = 'none'
        };
    }, 1000);
};
```

*HTML*

```
<a onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');" href="#"><b><u>Click to view</u></b></a>
<div id="foo" style=display:none;>TEXT</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tzAhy/1/)

Comment: Just a note: I would use `el` instead of `e`, since normally `e` is used for events.